# Django 3.0 MEDIA_ROOT and MEDIA_URL raise ImproperlyConfigured exception

Tags: python, django, django-settings, django-media

I am developing a Django app where the users have profiles, and they can upload a profile picture, the pictures will be stored inside media/profile_pics/ and media is located in my root project's directory. I followed the Django docs [1]: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development
to serve uploaded media files during development but I keep getting an exception that says:

`

```
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
  File "/Users/OpenMindes/Dev/web/django/mylatestprotfolio-django/src/portfolio/urls.py", line 27, in <module>
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
  File "/Users/OpenMindes/Dev/web/django/mylatestprotfolio-django/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/urls/static.py", line 22, in static
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Empty static prefix not permitted")
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Empty static prefix not permitted
```

`My project's settings file looks like that (I hided the secret key):`

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
#sekret key : i hide it
# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    #own apps
    'my_portfolio.apps.MyPortfolioConfig',
    'blog.apps.BlogConfig',
    'crud.apps.CrudConfig',
    'users.apps.UsersConfig',
    #third party
    'widget_tweaks',
    'crispy_forms',
    'django_cleanup',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'portfolio.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'portfolio.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEIDA_URL = '/media/'
#tell our crispy form what bootstrap version to use 
CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'
#redirect the user to the home page when successfully loged in
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'blog-home'
LOGIN_URL = 'login'
```

`And my project urls.py file looks like this:`

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
# Import the users views
from users import views as user_views
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
# To serve files during dev
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
urlpatterns = [
    path('',include('my_portfolio.urls')),
    path('blog/',include('blog.urls')),
    path('crud/',include('crud.urls')),
    path('register/', user_views.register, name='user-register'),
        #login and logout views
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='users/login.html'), name='login'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='users/logout.html'), name='logout'),
    #profiles
    path('profile/', user_views.profile, name='profile'),
    path('testing/', user_views.testingForm, name='testing'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
] 

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

`
I've looked at many solution provided in this platform but none of them seem to be working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo:

```
MEIDA_URL
```

It should be:

```
MEDIA_URL
```

Comment: No problem. Please accept my answer, since it helped you.